# How to numerically handle a double integral with a singular endpoint on the outer integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to numerically integrate

$$\int_0^a f(x) \int_{\sqrt{x}}^\infty \frac{\exp(-u^2)}{\sqrt{u^2-x}}du dx$$ where a is some positive real number and f(x) is some well behaved function. The inner integral is singular at 0 so the outer integral must be done using a method that can handle a singular end point. The inner integrand is also singular at the lower end point so it also needs to be handled in a similar way.

I have seen an integral like this done in a paper that claimed a "romberg method adapted to a singular endpoint" was used but I have not been able to find much on this method. I was curious if someone could explain how to handle this numerically. I was able to find this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812219090348N#) but it is not easy to see how to apply it to this problem.

**An additional comment the original question:** As was pointed out below the singularity at the lower bound of the u integral at $\sqrt{x}$ is removable (see post below). While this does simplify my task, the question on how to numerically deal with a singular endpoint remains since the lower limit for the x integral is a singular endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can eliminate the singularity for the inner integral at $u = \sqrt{x}$ with a variable transformation.
First let $s = u^2$, then

$$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(-u^2)}}{\sqrt{u^2-x}}du = \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(-s)}}{2\sqrt{s}\sqrt{s-x}}ds.$$

Then letting $t^2 = s-x$, we get

$$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{(-u^2)}}{\sqrt{u^2-x}}du = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp{[-(x+t^2)]}}{\sqrt{x+t^2}}dt.$$

That may help.

In general, if $f \in C([0,1])$, then for $n \geq 2$ the change of variable $t^n=x$ transforms an improper into a proper integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x^{-\frac1{n}}f(x)dx=n\int_{0}^{1} t^{n-2}f(t^n)dt$$

Furthermore, the integrand decays rapidly as $u \rightarrow \infty,$ so the semi-infinite domain should not present much difficulty. There are many approaches for infinite domains, in general, including Gauss-Laguerre and Gauss -Hermite quadrature.

Comment: You still have a singular end point for the outer integral because when x=0 the inner integral is still singular correct? While removing the singularity on the inner integration bound is helpful, my question on how to deal with a singular endpoint numerically remains.

Comment: That depends on the nature of $f$ which is unspecified here. A singularity at an end point is a problem with closed quadrature

Comment: What would I have to know about f to handle this situation? Do I have to know the form of the function or can I just know some properties about its behavior?

Comment: If you use open quadrature like Gauss - you wont have to dierctly evaluate at an undefined point -- but the accuracy can suffer. It best you remove all the internal singularities first anyway.  Then use open quadrature on the outer integration.

Comment: It would be nice to know the asymptotic behavior of $f$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Also I showed you how to remove a singularity in general -- again depending on $f$ it could be applied again.

Comment: What do you mean by open quadrature? Do you mean just ignore the endpoint and hope that it converges as you get close?

Comment: I apologize for all my questions... is it possible to answer the question with a restriction on the behavior of f? Is it enough to know that f is not blowing up at the singular point?

Comment: Guassian quadrature uses a weighted sum of the function at internal points (open).  Trapezoidal, Simpsons, etc involves the endpoint (closed).  Gaussian quadrature is generally more efficient and as I said has forms that automatically handle the infinite domain. Yes if f is not blowing up, then after above transformation you have a very weak remaining singularity which is avoided entirely with the open quadrature.